# ionic executeSql doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, mobile

I actually try to make an mobile app with SQLite. I juste try to create two tables:

```
constructor(private sqlite:SQLite,public modalCtrl: ModalController,public navCtrl: NavController, private navParam: NavParams, private databaseprovider: DatabaseProvider, private employeesProvider: EmployeeProvider) {
    this.createDetabaseFile();
}

private createDetabaseFile() : void {
    this.sqlite.create({
          name: DATABASE_FILE_NAME,
          location: 'default'
    }).then((dbRes: SQLiteObject) => {
        alert("bdd créée");
        this.db = dbRes;
        this.createTables();
    })
}

private createTables() : void {
    this.db.executeSql('CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS  symbole(id INTEGER NOT NULL ,name TEXT)',{})
        .then(() => {
            alert("table symbole created");
            this.db.executeSql('CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS representationPhoto(name VARCHAR(32))',{})
                .then(() => {
                    alert("table representationPhoto created");
                })
            .catch(e => alert("erreur creation table"));
        })
        .catch(e => alert("erreur creation table"));
}
```

And `db.executeSql()` seem not working, indeed, the `alert("table symbole created");` don't appear, however `alert("bdd créée")` appear, and the program don't triggered the catch.

Have you an idea?

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: can you try passing the dbRes like a parameter to createTables() method and using it instead of this.db?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try declaring db variable above createDetabaseFile function it seems to me the problem because you are using this.db without declaring it in the class scope.

Try doing this:

```
public db: any; // above createDetabaseFile function
```

Comment: If they don't declare db that program never runs

Comment: Kindly try changing name type in 1st executeSql to varchar

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `platform ready` block before handling `SQLite`.Try this:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(private platform: Platform, ...other imports) {
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.createDetabaseFile();
 })
}
```